# Replace ignorando tag e retornando como string

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Acho que já vi esse problema aqui uma vez, mas não consegui encontrar de jeito nenhum, nem pesquisando na internet (esqueci que palavras usar na pesquisa porque acho que já tratei disso antes mas me deu um branco total).

Estou fazendo um `replace` de um texto em uma `div` e inserindo algumas palavras entre as tags `<b></b>`.

Por exemplo:

```
<div id="texto">
    Qualquer texto aqui
</div>
```

Quero que a palavra "texto" fique entre `<b></b>` (negrito):

```
var texto_original = $("#texto").text();
$("#texto").text(texto_original.replace("texto","<b>texto</b>"));
```

Acontece que após o `replace` o texto na `div` fica assim:

```
Qualquer <b>texto</b> aqui
```

Quando o desejado seria assim:

> Qualquer **texto** aqui

Veja o exemplo:

```js
var texto_original = $("#texto").text();
$("#texto").text(texto_original.replace("texto","<b>texto</b>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="texto">
   Qualquer texto aqui
</div>
```

Ou seja, a tag está sendo tratada como string. Se não me engano existe um método que faz essa conversão, mas não estou lembrando de jeito nenhum. Como se resolve isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ser tratada como html tem que ser atribuida com a função [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```js
var texto_original = $("#texto").html();
$("#texto").html(texto_original.replace("texto","<b>texto</b>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="texto">
   Qualquer texto aqui
</div>
```

A ideia do `text` é precisamente essa, evitar que o que é colocado como conteúdo seja interpretado como html. Se for o usuário a introduzir o conteúdo, o `text` acaba por proteger contra injeção de javascript.

Comment: Putz!!! É mesmo!! rsrs